# how to extend array.push() in javascript such that after calling push method, element should not get pushed into the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example:

```
var animals = ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep'];

console.log(animals.push('cows'));
// expected output: 4

console.log(animals);
// expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows"]

animals.push('chickens');
```

//I want output such that, when i will push 'chickens' it should not get

```
pushed into the array.
console.log(animals);
// expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows"]
```

Comment: Why it should not push?

Comment: I want to change the push functionality, it should not push when push method called

Comment: Wait wait .. what ? When you push you don't want to get it push ? Well don't push then ;)

Comment: You can always override the array's prototype for the same `Array.prototpye.push = function(){}`. Now it won't push.

Comment: **I want to change the push functionality** <- For me, not a good idea. Just use a condition statement or something.

Comment: no my requirement is like that when i will call push method it should print "hii" but should not push any element

Comment: @kalyanigupta That's bad. Whats the purpose in changing the push function?

Comment: i knew, it's bad but i got  my requirement like that....

Comment: No requirement should you ever force into something like changing core code functionality. Doing so, most probably will break other code. The approach always has to be ... writing a method like e.g. `addAnimal` that does the required checks and the pushing/not pushing of the item. By the way that's also how a requirement should be expressed. Of course this approach does force one to replace every single occurrence of `animals.push( ... )` with `addAnimal( ... )`. That's what is called *refactoring*. Other programmers that read this new code now do exactly know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

> my requirement is like that when i will call push method it should
>   print "hii" but should not push any element

**Not a good idea**, but you can always **override the existing push function** by doing

```
Array.prototype.push = function(){ console.log("hii") };
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [1];
console.log(1,arr); //[1]

Array.prototype.push = function(){console.log("hii") };
arr.push(2); //hii
console.log(2,arr); //hii //[1]
```

**Note**

- You'll notice that `push` method is being called (internally) when the array is *initialized* and when its value is printed on `console`.

Comment: it should work (maybe not in `strict mode`) - but you can always do something like: `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'Push',{value:function(what){console.log(what, 'hii')}});` ... note the spelling is capital `P`

Answer (score 0):

From your situation the problem should me somewhere else because if you would modify native function, libraries that use it may start to return some weird values. but if you really want to do this, I suggest you wrap .push function with your own one using Array.prototype. You can read more about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype